# Reuse result after checking `is_ok`

Tags: rust

Here's a very simplified version of some code I'm working with:

```rust
fn my_func(i: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
    match i {
        42 => Ok(113),
        _ => Err("Can only use 42".to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    if my_func(42).is_ok() {
        println!("its ok");
    }
}
```

Within `main()`, there is a whole load of other `if` statements.

All I need is, if `my_func(42)` is ok, to, within the `println` statement, print the result.

I was hoping to be able to write something like

```rust
fn my_func(i: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
    match i {
        42 => Ok(113),
        _ => Err("Can only use 42".to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    if (let result = my_func(42)).is_ok() {
        println!("its ok, and result is: {:?}", result);
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way to write the above?

Comment: Are you looking for `if let Ok(_) = my_func(...)`? In any case, if the `if` expression captures what you want, why not use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `if let` patterns.

```
if let Ok(result) = my_func(42) {
  println!("It's ok, and result is {:?}", result);
}
```

`if let` attempts to bind the pattern on the left-hand side (`Ok(result)` in this case) against the value on the right-hand side. If the binding succeeds (that is, if `my_func(42)` is actually an `Ok` value), then the variable(s) in the pattern are bound and the inside of the block runs. If not, the block is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. if-let does what you want.  Here's the [chapter in The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html) on it.  For your example:

```rust
fn main() {
    if let Ok(result) = my_func(42) {
        println!("its ok, and result is: {:?}", result);
    }
}
```

That does exactly what you want, but the variable's value is confined to within the scope of the `if` statement's block.

2. There's a newer option since [1.65](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#let-else-statements), `let-else`.
   `let-else` is an option if you *need* success, or diverge:

```rust
fn main() {
    let Ok(result) = my_func(42) else {
        panic!("my_func failed!"); // Could also be a return statement
    }
    println!("result is a regular variable out here now!  Value: {:?}", result);
}
```

This means that you can confirm return values, or "get out", without nesting scopes infinitely.

I hope that's helpful.